# PHP / JAVASCRIPT / SQL Failing to show table

Tags: javascript, php, sql, search

I'm trying to create a query system to display all the user accounts within my system to the system admin, so that later I can add a feature to edit them, etc. I've created a PHP file to find the results and create a table, which is then echoed back to the javascript and displayed. However, the system only displays 0 and not the table. I can only assume this means that nothing was found, but my system is meant to have catches for this and I'm 90% sure it should be finding something.

**Javascript**

```
function UserSearch(){
var Search = $("#txtUserSearch" ).val();
var Type = $("#sltQuery" ).val()
$.post('../functions/php/fncusersearch.php', {Search: Search, Type: Type}, function(data) {
    if (data == 1){
        $('#divSearchResults').html('<p class="text-center text-danger bg-danger" id="pUPInc">No Accounts Matched your Search!</p>');
    }
    else if (data == 3){
        $('#divSearchResults').html('<p class="text-center text-danger bg-danger" id="pUPInc">Database not found! Please try again later.</p>');
    }
    else{
        $('#divSearchResults').html(data);
    }
});
```

}

**PHP**

```
//Retrieves variables from Javascript.
$Search = $_POST["Search"];
$Type = $_POST["Type"];

if ($Type == "Registration Date"){
    $Type = "joined";
}
else if ($Type == "Account Rank"){
    $Type = "rank";
}

include "db/openlogindb.php";
if($DBError == true){
    $data = 3;
}
else{

    $UserSearch = "SELECT username, surname, forename, joined, rank FROM users WHERE ".$Type." LIKE '%".$Search."%'";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $UserSearch);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0){
        $data = 1;
    }
    else{
        $data = '';
        $data += '<table class="table table-striped">';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
            $data += "<tr><td>".$row['surname']."</td><td>".$row['forename']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['joined']."</td><td>".$row['rank']."</td></tr>";
        }

        $data += "</table>";
    }
}

include "db/closelogindb.php";

echo $data;
?>
```

[image]

http://thomas-smyth.co.uk/admin/manageusers.php

Comment: Please don't store plaintext passwords

Comment: I don't see why it's passing 0, but you have the id of txtUserSearch on your div instead of your input, so your search field is never getting passed in.

Comment: Also, you're open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and `bind_param` for the search field.

Comment: The passwords are being stored in plain text purely for test purposes. At the moment I am often creating large numbers of accounts through phpMyAdmin for testing purposes. It would be very hard to do so if they had to be encrypted, furthermore if I was trying to make it secure for testing I wouldn't choose password as my password. Thanks for the the advice on the SQL injections, it was on my list to look into at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your using wrong operator for concatenation

```
$data += '<table class="table table-striped">';
```

replace + symbol with .

eg,

```
$data .= '<table class="table table-striped">';
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks! A bit silly of me, though I think it's a habit as I learnt python first where += is the operator to concatenate.